# Where to find iOS 7 frameworks Updation compare to iOS 6 frameworks

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mpmediaplayercontroller

As `Apple` New Operating System `iOS 7` is now released. So same as all updating my all `iOS App` for `iOS 7` But there is some confusion going on with this like.

**Problem**

One on my `iOS App` Used live Streaming through `Wowza Streaming Server` as on `iOS 5` or `iOS 6` with media player framework that build working fine but on iOS 7 Not working the same streaming url.(need to press play/pause 2-3 times then this link will play.)

**Looking**

Is there any way i can found what kind of changes Apple done in `iOS 7` media player framework So that i can resolve the issue of any other point any one want to share.

thanks

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link for [changes in iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1).

Changes / Enhancements in AV foundation framework are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW31).

Hope that helps.